# Does anyone know how to disable the swipe gesture in Flash Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I want to disable the swipe gesture for my android flash based game so it doesn't cause you to jump to the next or previous frame.

Thanks.

Comment: What is frame exactly? Your flash animation frame? Or you mean the device's various screens. If in Flash, then try adding a `boolean` to know when in/out of actual gameplay. When playing the boolean is `true` and swipe is ignored (empty function?), when `false` as in user is on menu screens etc then swipe function does the frame jumps required. Anyhow this link might help: [tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/) .. now If you dont want anything to happen when a swipe is detected then leave blank.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.NONE` at the point in your program where you want it disabed.